# Simplifying $ \frac{\sinh x}{xe^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}} = C \frac{\sinh y}{ye^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, hyperbolic-functions

I am searching for a simpler way of expressing the relationship between x and y given by the equation in the title where C is a known constant.

I recognize that the equation is of the form f(x)=Cf(y) where f is an even function that is increasing on (0,infinity). So when C = 1, we have |x|=|y|.

Any insight into the case when C is not 1 would be appreciated!

Comment: $$\frac{\sinh x}{x}e^{-x^2/2}\approx e^{-x^2/3},$$ hence an approximate solution is given by $$ y=\pm\sqrt{\log(C^3)-x^2}.$$

Comment: Very cool. Thanks! Do you have any ideas for an exact solution? My conjecture is that it's a hyperbola.

Comment: The approximate solution is given by an hyperbola, but the exact one is a solution of a trascendental equation, without any "nice" closed form.

Comment: Why can't the solution of a transcendental equation have a nice closed form? Or are you saying there isn't one for this case in particular?

Comment: For this case in particular, that strongly recalls $$\frac{x e^x}{y e^y}=C,$$ that can be solved only through Lambert $W$ function.

Comment: I will look that up. Thank you for your help!